# MySQL update field based on min value of another field when grouped by a third

Tags: mysql

I have read several threads on selecting for min, grouping etc but can't seem to create an efficient query to solve this.  Please forgive if duplicate.

I have a table like:

```
ID  Date    Value   Tag  
1   1/1/13  500 NULL  
2   1/1/13  10 NULL  
3   1/1/13  12 NULL  
4   1/2/13  99 NULL  
5   1/2/13  136 NULL  
6   1/2/13  17 NULL
```

Basically want an update query that populates the TAG field with a value of 1 when it has the lowest value grouped by date.  In this example that would be IDs 2 and 6.

update table set tag = 1 (select min?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by calculating the `min()` and using a `join` to do the filtering:

```
update t join
       (select date, min(value) as minvalue
        from t
        group by date
       ) tmin
       on t.date = tmin.date and t.value = tmin.minvalue
    set tag = 1;
```

Comment: this appears to be it, testing now and will update.  Thanks in advance though.

Comment: Seems so obvious now but seeing cross eyed.  THANK YOU for the bail-out.

Answer (score -3):

```
UPDATE `table` t
SET tag = 1
WHERE value = (SELECT MIN(value) FROM `table` t2 WHERE t.date = t2.date)
```

or

```
UPDATE `table` t
SET tag = 1
WHERE value <= ALL (SELECT value FROM `table` t2 WHERE t.date = t2.date)
```

Note that if there is a tie, `tag` will be `1` for each tied record.

Comment: Hello and thanks, tried this and get: #1093 - You can't specify target table 't' for update in FROM clause

Comment: You can do this in latest MariaDB