# Update Inner Join multiple matches only lowest ID

Tags: mysql, join

If I do an update join that can find several matches in a group but only want to update the min(ID) one how do I add that to the query?  So a basic version would look like this:

```
Update Table1 as T1
Inner Join Table2 as T2
On T1.Name=T2.Name
And T1.Value>=T2.MinValue
And T1.Value<=T2.MaxValue
Set T1.Flag='1'
```

In some groups I will get more than one match but in all cases I just want a single record in T1 updated as '1'. I know Min(ID) is involved somehow yet I'm not sure where in that query I can specify the Min(ID) for the found matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw a very similar question to yours here.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827114/mysql-update-field-based-on-min-value-of-another-field-when-grouped-by-a-third) somebody also wanted to set a flag, when the an value is the lowest, grouped by a column.
And I think this could solve your problem!